# Delete a directory from stage, from working folder, but keep in remote

Tags: git, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to remove a folder locally in GIT. but when I do push, to not push the changes.

After deleting the folder locally, i trying to add it to `/info/exclude` but it didn't help. The folder still appear as "delete" in status.

I also don't want, who use the same computer to be able to do `git checkuot HEAD~2` and get back the folder.

**In other words:** I am giving a private repository to my friend. The repository contain sensitive data. My friend don't have cerdentials to the git. So for each pull & push He will need my to type a password (it is good). I want to delete one folder from my friend computer, so he we will not be able to see it.

(For who asking why I deleting files from my friend computer... it's my computer, but I gave it to my friend for working on)

(I'm not asking about deleting history in GIT, because I want it still exists in history, for other users who clone the REPO)

(My friend computer is actually a `cloud9` so if you have another solution just for it, will be great)

If something unclear, please comment, I will improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I also don't want, who use the same computer to be able to do `git checkout HEAD~2` and get back the folder.

This, you cannot do.  If it's in the history, it's available to anyone.

The closest you can get is to either (a) set up a repository for sparse checkout,

```
printf %s\\n '*' '!path/to/folder' > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git config core.sparsecheckout true
git checkout
```

and from then on anyone who doesn't fiddle with the sparse checkout settings won't see the excluded folder in their checkouts, or (b) remove the folder from your distributed history and maintain a separate history in private repositories combining the public and private parts.

Comment: 1. Can I remove it from history only locally, but don't push to removed history to the remote?

Comment: 2. How exactly sparse-checkout helps?

Comment: It'll help in that no checkout in that repository will include that folder (unless somebody disables the sparse checkout), so _just_ doing the `git checkout HEAD~2` will have the effect you want, to get around it they'll have to disable sparse checkout, and also it'll help in that if that's enough, you don't have to remove the folder from history.

Comment: It's good idea, maybe will use it, But not secure. The folder still exists in the local REPO history. I'm searching for a secure way to remove it absolute from the system.
I'm not afraid that he will do "git pull", because I'm the only one we can do git pull. I have the credentials.

Comment: If you don't want people to have something, don't give it to them and then ask git to hide it from them. It's not ever going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `assume-unchanged` flag  to mark the file not to be tracked even if there are changes

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

#### --[no-]assume-unchanged

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>
> Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]

Comment: 1. What happen if I change it remotely the untracked files, and do `git pull`? what is it mean `you will need to hadle the situtation manually?`

Comment: 2. I also don't want the user to be able to recover the folder by doing `git checkout HEAD~2" `no-assume-unchaged` will work in this situation?

Comment: Will be back in an hour will answer both